# iPhone simulator takes minutes to launch using Xamarin.UITest

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.uitest

I'm trying to automate our Xamarin.Forms project (Android&iOS) and decided to try out Xamarin.UITest for some smoke testing.

I've managed to connect the app and using REPL I've also located the elements we wish to interact with.

**The issue:**
The test itself works, but when I try to run it, my iPhone simulator either freezes and/or restarts multiple times.
This means going through a simple login flow-test takes up to 5 minutes, where most of that is looking at a frozen simulator not launching my app.

The simulator will eventually launch and connect, although sometimes it appears to be running headless(!?), as my tests go through but I have no simulator open.

My app initializer:

```
public static IApp StartApp(Platform platform)
        {
            if (platform == Platform.Android)
            {
                return ConfigureApp.Android.StartApp();
            }
            //Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("UITEST_FORCE_IOS_SIM_RESTART", "1");
            IApp app = ConfigureApp.iOS            
                .StartApp(Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.AppDataMode.DoNotClear);            
            return app;
        }
```

(note I have tried with and without the AppDataMode parameter).

And my setup

```
        IApp app;
        Platform platform;

        public Tests(Platform platform)
        {
            this.platform = platform;
        }

        [SetUp]
        public void BeforeEachTest()
        {
            app = AppInitializer.StartApp(platform);
           
        }
```

My setup:

```
MacBook Pro 2020 running Big Sur (11.5.2) 
Visual Studio Community 8.10.8 
Xcode 12.5.1 
Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2012 
Xamarin.UITest 3.2.0

iPhone simulators tested:
iPhone 12 - iOS 14.4
iPhone 8 - iOS 14.4
iPhone SE (2nd gen) iOS 13.7
```

As a final note, when running the iOS project normally (just debugging), this behaviour is *not* observed. The rebooting & freezing *only* occurs on UITests.

Comment: Hi , can you try this in a blank project to see if problem persists?

Comment: Thank you for this (albeit obvious) question! I have just tried this in a new project, and I'm not having the same issues. I've also noticed that the blank project **doesn't** close my simulator between tests, so I'm definitely going to have a look at my setup. I think it's safe to say the issue isn't within Xamarin.UITest.

Comment: That's fine, if you have any other problem please let me know.